# put the highchart legend to the bottom of the chart and horizontally centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Im using [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) for my website that requires a chart and It renders good (no problem at all) however, due to conflict requirements, I want the legend to be put on the bottom (below the chart, move it from the right side to the bottom side) and make it horizontally centered anyone knows how to make it? I tried this (refer below)

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    floating: true,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    align:'right',
    y:40
},
```

my overall chart code is

```
$('#chart_portfolio').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                        borderColor: '#ff0000',
                        width: null,
                        height: null
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: false,
                            x: -20 //center
                        },
                        legend: {
                            enabled: true,
                            floating: true,
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                            align:'center'       
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: portfolio_creation_date //this is an array
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: false
                            },
                            plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#ff0000'
                            }]
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                                shared: true,
                                crosshairs: true
                            },

                        series: [{
                            name: 'Future',
                            data: portfolio_future, //this is an array
                            color: '#0f00ff'
                        }, {
                            name: 'In Grace Period',
                            data: portfolio_ingrace_period, //this is an array
                            color: '#fda800'
                        }, {
                            name: 'Arrears',
                            data: portfolio_in_arrears, //this is an array
                            color: '#f40404'
                        }, {
                            name: 'Good standing',
                            data: portfolio_good_standing, //this is an array
                            color: '#4da74d'
                        }]
                    }); //end of highcharts
```

but sadly not working. Please refer below image for a sharp detail.

[image: refer to the image]

Comment: Other that needing `align: 'center'` to get the legend in the middle, what you have should work. Can you post a working example of your problem.

Comment: How about removing all options and using defaults? That's where is legend is placed by default..

Comment: **bump** - as I said, disable options, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ctfcnsrL/1/ Or maybe you are suing somewhere `setOptions()`? Don't forget to clear the cache!

Comment: thank you, its working now, please post your answer so that I can accept right away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove options, to use default ones:  http://jsfiddle.net/ctfcnsrL/1/

```
                    legend: {
                        // enabled: true,
                        // floating: true,
                        // verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        // align:'center'       
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this One

```
legend: {
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            align:'center',           
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ctfcnsrL/

Comment: i tried yours and merge it with my code yet still not working, please see my updated post.